# How can I know disk usage with unmounted disk?

Tags: linux

As far as I know, `du` or `df` can be used in **MOUNTED** partition only. I don't want to mount them, but I wanna know their usage, What command I can peek that info?

Comment: See http://serverfault.com/questions/190685/whats-the-best-way-to-get-info-about-currently-unmounted-drives for some useful info (possible duplicate?)

Comment: I'd say tune2fs is most likely the right answer to this problem, as pointed in question pointed out above.

Answer (score 1):

you can try

tune2fs -l /dev/sdx (your unmounted parition)

or

parted /dev/sdx print al

Answer (score 0):

Untested but GNU df supports --direct. I don't have access to any linux at the moment. But give it a try.

```
df --direct /dev/sda2
```

Comment: Sounded nice, but my debian testing doesn't have this flag.

Comment: That flag doesn't return correct infomation.